# Hibernate 4 + Spring Data CrudRepository, CLI application: failed to lazily initialize a collection: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to run Spring-based CLI application which uses Spring Data CrudRepository to access Hibernate4-based persistence layer implemented using JPA annotations over MySQL5 (InnoDB) database using c3p0 connection pool.

I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <package>.entity.User.categories, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <package>.entity.User.categories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I'm newbie with Spring Data and Hibernate. From my point of view it's an issue with two different transactions (one in `UserServiceImpl::findByLogin` and another in `CategoryServiceImpl::deleteByUser`). Changing `User` entity to use Eager fetch type for Categories helps, but I want to use lazy loading in this method.

Can I still use lazy fetch type in `UserServiceImpl::findByLogin` and fetch dependent objects in service consumer later with `CrudRepository` and Spring-managed transactions in Service Layer?

Excerpt from the application which causes an exception:

```
    User user = userService.findByLogin(login);
    categoryService.deleteByUser(user);
```

---

EDIT: I tried to use `EntityManager::merge`, but with no luck:

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService, InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Category findById(Long categoryId) {
        return repository.findOne(categoryId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Category save(Category category) {
        return repository.save(category);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Category category) {
        repository.delete(category);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteByUser(User user) {
        entityManager.merge(user);
        repository.delete(user.getCategories());
    }
}
```

---

Services (injected with `@Autowired`):
User service:

```
package <package>.service.jpa;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import <package>.entity.User;
import <package>.repository.UserRepository;
import <package>.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(repository.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User findById(Long userId) {
        return repository.findOne(userId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User findByLogin(String login) {
        return repository.findByLogin(login);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User save(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(User user) {
        repository.delete(user);
    }
}
```

Category service:

```
package <package>.service.jpa;

import <package>.entity.Category;
import <package>.entity.User;
import <package>.repository.CategoryRepository;
import <package>.service.CategoryService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Category findById(Long categoryId) {
        return repository.findOne(categoryId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Category save(Category category) {
        return repository.save(category);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Category category) {
        repository.delete(category);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteByUser(User user) {
        repository.delete(user.getCategories());
    }
}
```

Entities:
User:

```
package <package>.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private int version;
    private String login;
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    private Set<CategoryFeed> categoryFeeds = new HashSet<CategoryFeed>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Version
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        categories.add(category);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<CategoryFeed> getCategoryFeeds() {
        return categoryFeeds;
    }

    public void setCategoryFeeds(Set<CategoryFeed> categoryFeeds) {
        this.categoryFeeds = categoryFeeds;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }

        User user = (User) o;

        if (login != null ? !login.equals(user.login) : user.login != null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Category:

```
package <package>.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"userId", "title"}))
public class Category {
    public static final String ROOT_CATEGORY_TITLE = "";

    private Long categoryId;
    private int version;
    private User user;
    private String title = ROOT_CATEGORY_TITLE;

    private Set<CategoryFeed> feeds = new HashSet<CategoryFeed>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @Version
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<CategoryFeed> getFeeds() {
        return feeds;
    }

    public void setFeeds(Set<CategoryFeed> feeds) {
        this.feeds = feeds;
    }

    public void addFeed(CategoryFeed feed) {
        this.feeds.add(feed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }

        Category category = (Category) o;

        if (title != null ? !title.equals(category.title) : category.title != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (user != null ? !user.equals(category.user) : category.user != null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = user != null ? user.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this code:

```
User user = userService.findByLogin(login);
categoryService.deleteByUser(user);
```

within a single transaction like so:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteCategoriesByUser(String login) {
    User user = userService.findByLogin(login);
    categoryService.deleteByUser(user);
}
```

which will make sure the same Hibernate session is used for both operations.

Comment: I think it's rather a workaround. In my case logic is conditional. I have to fetch user anyway, but depending on flag I want to remove all his categories. Is it possible to have two separate general-purpose methods, one for fetching user by login and second to remove all categories of the specific user. And I don't want to fetch user second time in `deleteCategoriesByUser` method because I already fetched the user. And `deleteCategoriesByUser` method don't have to know such implementation details as fetching categories again. Is there any best practice or issue in my architecture?

Comment: Maybe I should wrap `User user = userService.findByLogin(login);
if (...) {categoryService.deleteByUser(user);}` my CLI application code into transaction? But from my point of view it's another workaround rather than best practice. As I understand I should somehow tell hibernate that it should fetch User's categories using curent connection and transaction. But I don't know how.

Comment: But you already DO know how to do it. Just wrap the code in a transaction and you are good to go. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: That, or the one with the conditional delete you proposed. Either way, sharing the transaction (and Hibernate Session thereof) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is to do with transaction, you seem to have setup your declarative transaction boundaries properly (default Spring transaction propagation is REQUIRED -- meaning if you call nested method decorated with `@Transactional`, no overlapping transaction is created)

Your problem seem to be cause by `categories` property of the user object not populated when you're fetching it (because you set it to lazy) AND/OR hibernate unable to populate it before session is closed on `deleteByLogin` -- hence the object is already detached.

As fas as I can see there are two method to resolve this:

**1. Eagerly fetch the categories property of a user**

Mark `categories` property as eagerly fetched: `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, ...)` (WARNING: could eat massive amount of memory), or use `LEFT JOIN FETCH` syntax when querying for a user so its `categories` property is populated

```
select distinct u from User as u left join fetch u.categories where u.login = :login
```

**2. Merge the detached user on `deleteByLogin`**

On `deleteByLogin`, merge the user object first into the persistence context so the `categories` property can be lazily loaded whenever you call `getCategories()`

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteByUser(User user) {
    session.merge(user);
    repository.delete(user.getCategories());
}
```

Comment: Why `categories` are detached by `findByLogin`? Because the boundary of the transaction ends at the end of the method? 1. I want to use lazy associations for performance reasons. `findByLogin` is a general purpose method, and in most cases associations will not be used. 2. I am using standard JPA annotations. Is it OK to use hibernate-specific classes? And how can I receive the instance of session in `CrudRepository`?

Comment: Entity objects are commonly detached before being passed to view, otherwise when your view layer queries the properties exceptions will start flying out. **Note that detached means any query / modification to the Java object will NOT be propagated to database**. To put a detached entity back into persistence context you have to "merge" it. For standard JPA you can do `em.merge(objname)` where em is EntityManager reference.

Comment: Just to clarify, is anything outside method marked with `@Transactional`annotation treated as a view layer? Is it true even in CLI application?

Comment: Not really. On a typical MVC (Model View Controller) pattern you have DAO, Service, Controller and View classes. Entity objects are normally fetched / saved at DAO and manipulated by Service. Controller only has necessary code to translate user requests into Service classes calls (which returns entity object collections / "models") and passes it to Views. Normally only DAO / Service classes methods' has `@Transactional` annotation

Comment: In my case (CLI application) I have DAO, Service & Controller (`main` method of CLI app). Are entity objects being detached before returning to Controller?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact you have CLI application. As soon as the method decorated with `@Transactional` returns, the transaction manager will close the transaction and detach the objects. Please read more on hibernate reference manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html